# v-if not reactive (or data not reactive)

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have following vue component (I have removed rest of the code just to point out this issue).

```
<template>
    <span splitpanes-default="70">
      Details Pane
            <uploader v-if="isUpload" class="uploader-example">
                <uploader-unsupport></uploader-unsupport>
                <uploader-drop>
                    <p>Drop files here to upload or</p>
                    <uploader-btn>select files</uploader-btn>
                    <uploader-btn :directory="true">select folder</uploader-btn>
                </uploader-drop>
                <uploader-list></uploader-list>
            </uploader>
    </span>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import uploader from 'vue-simple-uploader';

Vue.use(uploader);

@Component()
export default class In extends Vue {

  public isUpload: boolean = false;

  public upload() {
      this.isUpload = true;
  }

 }
</script>
```

when I call upload method (let's say on click of button), "isUpload" property is setting to true, but uploader is not showing back.

Seems like property is not reactive. what do I need to make it reactive.

Comment: Code looks good.  Are you sure it is not just hidden by CSS?  Add  `<div v-if="isUpload">UPLOAD IS SET</div>` right before, or even replacing existing `uploader` element.  And also check the component that includes this component...

Comment: yes. if i remove this condition it is visible. many other v-if also working. only this one is having issue

Comment: this is strange, even if i remove uploader and keep somple span, then also not working

Comment: If you view the html the source, and search for 'UPLOAD IS SET ', is it there?  If so, it is your CSS.

Comment: @StevenSpungin I couldnt find any such text on page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned down that it was issue with splitpanes (that outer part I didn't include in the question as I felt that wasn't relevant).

So splitepane with property "watch-slots" should be there to make inner content (fully) reactive.

Reference: https://antoniandre.github.io/splitpanes/#in-depth-reactivity

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:key=""` on that component

```
<template>
    <span splitpanes-default="70">
      Details Pane
        <span v-if="isUpload">
            <uploader :key="uploaderKey" class="uploader-example">
                <uploader-unsupport></uploader-unsupport>
                <uploader-drop>
                    <p>Drop files here to upload or</p>
                    <uploader-btn>select files</uploader-btn>
                    <uploader-btn :directory="true">select folder</uploader-btn>
                </uploader-drop>
                <uploader-list></uploader-list>
            </uploader>
        </span>
    </span>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import uploader from 'vue-simple-uploader';

Vue.use(uploader);

@Component()
export default class In extends Vue {
  uploaderKey = 0;
  public isUpload: boolean = false;


  public upload() {
      this.uploaderKey = this.uploaderKey + 1;
      this.isUpload = true;
  }

 }
</script>
```